# How is a Ghoul's Paralysis DC calculated?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, undead, difficulty-class

So I was looking at making a character that used [necrografts](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/necrograft/), and as such, was looking at various undead abilities that I could attach to myself (With DM permission) and that's when I came upon the [Ghoul](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/ghoul). These creatures have a DC13 paralyzing touch, and according to the entry for paralysis, the DC should be 10+1/2 racial HD + con mod.

So this is where I became confused. Ghouls have no Con. and 2hd. Why is the DC 13 and not 11?

Moving into the realm of more obscure RAW rulings, If I were to [necrograft](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/necrograft/) this onto myself or others, would the DC use my class HD as players don't tend to have racial HD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the DC is calculated using Charisma for [Undead Creatures](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Undead):

> No Constitution score. Undead use their Charisma score in place of their Constitution score when calculating hit points, Fortitude saves, and **any special ability that relies on Constitution**(such as when calculating a breath weapon’s DC).

If you, a humanoid (or so I hope), were to obtain that ability, it would be based on your Constitution and not your Charisma. But if you happened to become an undead, the DC would be based on your Charisma instead.

And yes, player characters have a [Hit Dice](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Hit-Dice-HD-) equal to their total class levels:

> **As a creature gains levels, it gains additional Hit Dice**. Monsters, on the other hand, gain racial Hit Dice, which represent the monster’s general prowess and ability.

Comment: Yes, I am aware players have HD, but the ability stated racial HD, and was clarifying they would be used the same way in regards to that ability! Thanks!

Comment: A *raw* reading suggests that it wouldn't consider your class levels. Just how a dragon that takes fighter level does not increase their breath weapon's DC. Can you tell us how you obtained this paralyzing touch?

Comment: As described in my question, necrografts allow you to take undead parts and  attach them to yourself or others and the page I linked to provides commonly sold necrografts based off undead parts. (Would it be similar to that of the stranglers tongue necrograft with a flat set DC?)

Comment: I don't recall any example like that, so all we have are those common grafts as basis. We enter homebrewing territory then. The [ghoul corruption](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/corruption/ghoul/) seems to use your character level instead of racial HD.

Comment: Stranglers tongue is a flat DC15 will, and the creature it is take from uses the same paralysis ability, but basing it off of ghoul corruption is an interesting idea. It also seems that sorcerer's of the Ghoul Bloodline, get claws that cause paralysis as per the ghoul ability. It doesnt seem to state what the DC is, only that it is fort based, but it does state that if you are a ghoul with this ability "your levels in sorcerer stack with your racial Hit Dice when determining the DC of your paralysis" So I assume it would not scale with Class HD normally.

Comment: Your assumption seems to be correct. The fixed DC seems to be due to the fact that necrografts are treated as magic items, as such they have a set "caster level" that defines the item's power. A mohrg's paralysis is DC 21, while the necrograft is only DC 15. My only guess is that the author based this DC on the *Hold Person* spell (see the requirements), which is 3rd level and added 1/2 the item's caster level (5th) to define the DC.